# spring @Value int autoparse like floats

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

when I have values in a property file and read them in like

```
@Value(${ftpserver.maxconnections})
private float maxConnections;
```

It works and spring auto parse a value if it is 0f.
However there is no f,l,d for integer but I need an int.
If I just write the number without any postfix Spring complains that it cannot parse a java.lang.String to int.
According to various Internet sources it should work, but it does not.

I set the file like

```
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
```

and in the same configuration file

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer pspc() {
   return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

To recap I want this to work

```
@Value(${ftpserver.maxconnections})
private float maxConnections;
```

and not get an Exception for cannot parse String to int from the Spring ContextLoader.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a `ConversionService` :

```
@Bean 
public ConversionService conversionService() {
    return new DefaultConversionService();
}
```

You can't define this `conversionService()` in the same class as the one using this @Value (because the converter will not be initalized)

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the Object in the properties file to an int using this:
`@Value("#{T(java.lang.Integer).parseInt('${property.name:{number}}')}")`